# Input Requirement for Gaussian to Flat-Top Conversion

Tags: optics

I'm considering using a flat-top beam profile for laser micromachining instead of a Gaussian intensity profile. However, I don't want to lose the benefits of focusing a Gaussian profile rather than a flat-top one. As a result, I was wondering if the conversion step could be performed on an uncollimated beam (in my case, a high power focused beam). My research indicates that this isn't the case. Why not?